# Extract first lines from blocks of dates incremented by one day

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file with only date column. I am trying to write a shell script which will extract the date only if the next *n* number of rows are incremented by one day from the previous date. In the example below, *n* is limited to only 5.

I am new to using `awk` and `sed` command so here's my approach with basic commands. Multiple condition in the `while` loop seems not to be working.

Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -f
set -xv
exec 2>/myLog.txt
file="file1.txt"
counter=1
limit=5
while ((( $counter < $limit )) || (read Line));
do
    a=$Line
    for ((i=1;i<=$limit;i++));
    do
        read Line
        b=$Line
        if [ $a != `date --date="$b -1 day" '+%Y-%m-%d'` ]; then
            a=$b
        $i=0
        $counter=1
        else
        a=$b
        #read Line
        ((counter++))
        echo "$counter"
        fi
done

done < $file
```

**File1.txt:**

```
2000-04-03
2000-05-04
2000-06-03
2000-06-30
2000-10-14
2000-10-15
2000-10-16
2000-10-17
2000-10-18
2000-10-19
...
..
.
```

**Output.txt**

```
2000-10-14
```

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166) (ignore if you're not asking about hw). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Re "*extract the date only if the next n number of rows are incremented by next date from previous date.*": this description is annoyingly vague.  Based on the output, I'm ***guessing*** that the goal is to show the first item (*i.e.* a date) of every run of one-day-apart dates.

Comment: @Barmar I just saw your comment and added my efforts. Thanks

Comment: @Avi, See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Mash-up of [`numinterval`](http://suso.suso.org/programs/num-utils/), `date`, `paste`, `uniq` and `sed`:

```
# fake `numinterval` function, uncomment if `num-utils` can't be installed
# numinterval() { printf '%s %s r - p\n' $(sed '1!{$!p}') | dc ; }

date -f file1.txt '+%s' | numinterval | paste file1.txt - | 
uniq -f 1 | sed -n '/\t86400$/s/\t.*//p'
```

Output:

```
2000-10-14
```

---

How it works:

1. Convert all the dates to seconds, (`%s` means *"seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC"*), and use `numinterval` to output a
   list of differences.  The output of `date -f file1.txt '+%s' | numinterval` is:

   ```
   2678400
   2592000
   2332800
   9158400
   86400
   86400
   86400
   86400
   86400
   ```
2. `paste` dates and intervals together.
3. use `uniq -f 1` to remove all but the first of a series of lines with duplicate intervals in the *2nd* field, (`-f 1` skips the *1st* field),
4. use `sed` to look for any trailing *86,400*, (the number of seconds in a
   day), then delete that `86400` leaving the preceding date field, which is `p`*rint*ed.

Comment: numinterval seems not be working. Here is the error I get when i run the code. 
paste: file.txt-bash: numinterval: command not found
: No such file or directory
date: `file.txt': No such file or directory

I changed the file name to the correct file. It was still unable to find the file.

Comment: @Avi, That error means `numinterval` is not installed.  On *Debian/Ubuntu* systems run `apt install num-utils`, for other Linux distros, see [here](http://www.control-escape.com/linux/lx-swinstall.html).

Comment: I also don't have numinterval installed.. could you please share the output of "date -f file1.txt '+%s' | numinterval" .. wanted to have a look at it

Comment: @stack0114106, See revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
min_array=()
prev=""
i=0
limit=30
while read LINE
do
     curr=$LINE
     [ "$prev" = ""  ] && prev="$curr"  && continue  # next line 

     [ `date --date="$curr -1 day" '+%Y-%m-%d'` != "$prev"  ] && i=0 || ((i++))

if (("$i"==1)); then min_array=($prev); fi

     if (("$i"==30)); then echo "${min_array[*]}"; exit; fi

     prev="$curr"
done <$file
```

Comment: @Nic3500, The *OP* is *Avi*, who also wrote this answer.

Comment: Thanks @agc I was able to get the desired output without numinterval